# Computing a Gaussian posterior from a Gaussian prior and likelihood function in R

Tags: r, bayesian, bayes

I'm new to both R and Bayesian statistics, and I have a problem where I have a normally distributed prior that elicits a mean and standard deviation.  The introduced likelihood function is also normally distributed with a mean and standard deviation that can be drawn from a sample.

Now I understand that a posterior is formed that will also be normally distributed.  I have been asked to generate this in R, but I cannot find an example of R code where the posterior is formed from a normally distributed prior and likelihood function.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.  Thanks.

Comment: Well generally speaking, one would normally start with some algebra, and then worry about code implementation. [In *some cases* some particular package may be able to take out the need to do some of the algebra (perhaps symbolically, or via some numerical calculation), but in many situations you would do it yourself. It's not onerous, mostly involving simple operations like completing a square in an exponent.]

Comment: Which part exactly are you supposed to do in R?

Comment: Some closely related examples of what @Glen_b is suggesting can be found with a [site search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+conjugate+prior+[r]+is%3Aanswer).

Comment: @jsk If proceeding algebraically, a few things would still be done - the calculation of the sample mean and variance and the part where you draw a plot of the posterior (via `dnorm`). But I suspect the OP has omitted something important from the question that changes things, and I'm guessing it will come to light soon. I presumed that answering the question as it stood might speed that revelation up.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume since you're new to Bayesian analysis that you're supposed to do this through conjugate updating.

You understand that the posterior distribution is normal, but how exactly is this known? For certain priors we know the exact relationships between prior, likelihood, and posterior: [see here for a handy table.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Table_of_conjugate_distributions) Your situation is probably contained within this table, though it may require some reflection on your part to decide which prior you are actually using (i.e., known or unknown variance). These posterior updates are obtained by working through the algebra of 
$$
\text{Posterior}(\theta \mid \text{data}) \propto \text{Likelihood}(\text{data} \mid \theta) \times \text{Prior}(\theta).
$$
It may be useful, since you claim to be new to Bayesian analysis, to work through this calculation for your problem and see exactly the algebraic relationship between the prior(s) and the data and how they form the posterior parameters found in the table linked above. (Hint: the proportionality constant is related to the constant which would make the distribution integrate to 1 on the whole support).

Now, once you have the posterior distribution fully specified, you are theoretically done. If you need concrete evidence of your success (or even want to check how reasonable the values are), you can do sampling on your posterior through the built-in `rnorm` function, or you can plot the actual distribution values through `dnorm` on a grid of appropriate values.